# using axios response through axios.get

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In EMACSsCRIPT 6 code with React, if we use

```
var raxios = axios.get(some_server_link).then(function()(response) {
        .....
        use    response   data
        ....

});
```

I notice that I can only use response inside the function. Is there any way to be able to use response's info out of this function scope?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I am using React and ECMAScript 6. There might be a different solution here

Comment: It doesn't matter which library you are using. Request are still async, promises are still promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the response as state?

```
axios.get('/url')
  .then(res => {
  this.setState({ someKey: res.data });
}
```

Then you should be able to use it outside using:

```
this.state.someKey;
```

Comment: No, I did not. I am trying to use react-bootstrap-table and to implement your answer I might have to extend it, some how. thx

Comment: he is using `es6`, this way it will throw the error `can't read setState of undefined`, you need to use `arrow function` inside `.then` or use `.bind(this)` to `bind` the `context` :)

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga no problem if you are using `react-bootstrap-table`, store the data in state variable and assign that variable to `data` field of table, it will work :)